# How to construct an abelian variety with CM by a given CM field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $F$ be a totally real number field, and let $K$ be a quadratic extension of $F$ which cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}$. 
Then $K$ is a so called CM field.
For instance, take $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8) = F(i)$ where $\zeta_8$ is a primitive complex $8$-th root of unity.
Denote by $\mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of integers of $K$.
My question is:

> How to construct a number field $L$ and an abelian variety $A/L$ such that $\mathrm{End}(A) \cong \mathcal{O}_K ?$

For an example with elliptic curves, take $F = \mathbb{Q}$, and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$ so that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$.
Evidently, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ so $E_0 = \mathbb{C}/\mathcal{O}_K$ is an elliptic curve with $\mathcal{O}_K \subseteq \mathrm{End}(E_0)$.
Since $\mathrm{End}(E_0)$ is an order in an imaginary quadratic number field, we have $\mathrm{End}(E_0) \cong \mathcal{O}_K$ as $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the maximal order.
Furthermore, $j(E_0)$ is an algebraic number (in fact, an algebraic integer) which generates a field isomorphic to $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
It follows that we can define an elliptic curve $E_1/L$ such that $j(E_1) = j(E_0)$ so that $E_1 \cong_{\mathbb{C}} E_0$ and in particular $\mathrm{End}(E_1) \cong \mathrm{End}(E_0) \cong \mathcal{O}_K$ as required.

> Can I tell a similar story (with abelian vaieties instead of elliptic curves) for any CM field?

It is only clear to me that the answer is positive for imaginary quadratic number fields.

Comment: Yes. Your notation "End($A$)" must mean endomorphisms after scalar extension to $\mathbf{C}$. The endomorphisms over $\mathbf{C}$ all descend to a common finite extension of $L$; this has arithmetic significance for elliptic curves in terms of a ring class field (for the CM order), and such descent for endomorphisms (really from $\mathbf{C}$ to $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$) fails badly for projective spaces. See Theorem 1.7.2.1 and Prop. 1.7.4.5 in the book "Complex Multiplication and Lifting Problems" for an affirmative answer (with no explicit $L$) using modern algebraic geometry.

Comment: @nfdc23 could you please expand your comment to an answer? I have hard time finding this book.

Comment: If your university doesn't have a copy of that book then ask the library to get it for you via inter-library loan. Rather than explaining much that is already documented in detail there, I should point out that section A.4.6 in that book (see especially Corollary A.4.6.5) gives an improvement on Borovoi's comment below by avoiding any need to split the 3-torsion (building on a complete treatment of the Main Theorem of CM and its "converse" using modern algebraic geometry in A.2--A.3).

Comment: @nfdc23 Thanks for your help, I will do the reading.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonably good answer to your question of finding a number field $L$ is given in the comments to [Is there an excplicit number field of definition for an Abelian Variety $A/\mathbb{C}$ with CM?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177945/is-there-an-excplicit-number-field-of-definition-for-an-abelian-variety-a-math?rq=1) . However, the answer is roughly "no, there's no easy way to find $L$". But first you need to understand the difference between the field of moduli and fields of definition. For elliptic curves, the field of moduli is generated by the $j$-invariant (and if you also want the CM maps defined, you need to adjoin $j$ to the CM field, at least if $\text{End}(A)$ is the full ring of integers). For abelian varieties, the field of moduli is the field generated by the point in moduli space, or alternatively the fixed field of
$$ \{\sigma\in\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q) : \sigma(A)\cong A\}.$$
But there need not be a model for $A$ that is defined over this field. There's a brief discussion of CM abelian varieties in Shimura's *Introduction to the Arithmetic Theory of Automorphic Forms* (Section 5.5). More detailed information is in books on CM abelian varieties such as those by Shimura-Taniyama and Lang.

Comment: So do you know what is the answer in the case of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ mentioned by me in the beginning of my question?

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, such $L$ does exist. One can compute  a field over which $A$ together with a polarization, the action of $L$ with given CM-type, and the points of order 3 is defined. In particular, $A$ is defined over this field. This field is given by the theory of Shimura-Taniyama. See e.g. Deligne, Travaux de Shimura.